# c# How do I count the total of combined element values using XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XElement fragment containing thousands of entries. I need to be able to count the combined value of the qty elements for each unique ID element

So as an example, i have a hundreds of consumable items (supplies) for repair procedures, each with with a unique ID (see below). The ID might be called up 50 times in my XElement fragment if it's a consumable that's used a lot, and it might have a value of more than 1 in the qty element.
I need to iterate over my XElement fragment, counting the total sum of the value of the qty elements for each of the IDs.

```
<supplies>
     <supply>
        <id>104</id>
        <qty>1</qty>
     </supply>
     <supply>
        <id>27</id>
        <qty>1</qty>
     </supply>
     <supply>
        <id>104</id>
        <qty>5</qty>
     </supply>
     <supply>
        <id>104</id>
        <qty>10</qty>
     </supply>
     <supply>
        <id>16</id>
        <qty>2</qty>
     </supply>
</supplies>
```

In this example i need to add up the value all the qty elements for supply ID 104 (which is 16 in this example), then value for all the supply ID 27 (which is 1) and the same for supply ID 16 (which is 2). I need to do this for hundreds of unique IDs.

I'm not bothered how the sum total for each of them is presented to me, it can be by adding an element to each ID if necessary called 'Total' perhaps.

Any idea how to achieve this please?

Comment: Use LINQ to XML. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service - what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. I'd guessed linq to XML hence the tag. Just looking for a pointer. Not to worry though.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with LINQ, for this you need to use `group ... by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xml linq and a dictionary to get desired results

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<int, int> dict = doc.Descendants("supply")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("id"), y => (int)y.Element("qty"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Sum());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. Very helpful.